# How to correctly add jar library?

Tags: java, exception, jdbc, intellij-idea

I have a programm uses JDBC. 
In intellij Idea programm run correctly, but in cmd after i compile class and run it i have Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/blabla
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Run from cmd with this command:

```
java -cp .;"D:\libs\poi-3.14-20160307.jar" Main
```

What's the problem?

I'm add source code by requestion.

Comment: Please show us the source code that makes the database call. It sounds like you don't have the JDBC driver in the classpath when you run it from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`poi-3.14-20160307.jar` doesn't look like the jdbc driver jar. Use [this](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

After you download the jar, unzip, place it where you want and then include it in your classpath like:

`java -cp .;"D:\libs\poi-3.14-20160307.jar;D:\libs\mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar" Main`

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your classpath to make sure you have the mysql driver in place.

Things like Maven are very good at controlling the classpath, and making sure you build with the correct libraries.

What does the build script look like in IntelliJ? How is the jar packaged?

Does your code contain `Class.forName` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add MySQL driver for Java on the classpath. Try this one https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/